# How to bind various implementations of interface in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have a list of multiple implementations of an interface.

```
public class MyInterfaceImplementation1 extends MyInterface {}

public class MyInterfaceImplementation2 extends MyInterface {}
```

...

```
List<MyInterface> myInterfaceImplementationList;
myInterfaceImplementationList.add(new MyInterfaceImplementation1);
myInterfaceImplementationList.add(new MyInterfaceImplementation2);
```

List is passed into my implementation of AbstractModule, where I would like to bind them dynamically based on concrete Class.
Something like:

```
for (MyInterface c : myInterfaceImplementationList) {
  bind(c.getClass()).toInstance(c); //this is not OK
}
```

Now, is this possible in Guice and how?

Later I would like to access concrete implementation:

```
injector.getInstance(MyInterfaceImplementation1.class);
injector.getInstance(MyInterfaceImplementation2.class);
...
```

Comment: Can you describe why the `bind(getClass()).toInstance()` option is not OK? If you're trying to get multiple instances of your interface implementations, can you confirm whether your implementations have zero-arg or `@Inject`-annotated constructors? FWIW, [multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings) is a common solution when talking about binding sets and maps, though it's designed for cases where bindings are distributed among modules; you have an exhaustive list in one place, so it might only be valuable for its automated bindings of `Map<K, Provider<V>>` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

What I could do is:

```
for (MyInterface c : myInterfaceImplementationList) {
  bind(MyInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(c.getClass().getName())).toInstance(c); 
}
```

and then:

```
(MyInterfaceImplementation1) injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyInterface.class, Names.named(MyInterfaceImplementation1.class.getName())));
```

But this is a bit convoluted. Any better suggestion?

Comment: Would need to see exactly how you're using the `injector` in order to determine this.  Generally speaking this is the correct way to add multiple (singular) implementations.   Although using `injector#getInstance()` is pretty specific, normally you'd try to use `injector#requestInjection()` passing in the class which uses `@Inject @Named("Custom1") MyInterface myInterface;`.   It all depends on how your classes which use `MyInterface` are actually using it.

Comment: Your suggestion with Inject annotation and Named annotation is an option, but in that case one needs to know how was instance annotated.
If possible I would like to use:
`@Inject MyInterfaceImplementation1 myInterfaceImplementation1`

Comment: If you @inject the implementation directly you don't need to bind anything, guice will pickup the implementation exactly as you've requested if it's in the class path.

Comment: You only really need to bind for named annotations, type implementations (generics), multiple implementations (maps) or factories and providers.